What are the legal values at offset 0x30 in the Risc OS AIF header
I'm now poking around in the binary executable file format of the Acorn Archimedes family of computers, Arm Image Format or AIF.
It doesn't have a magic word but the *nix file utility identifies them by the swi OS_Exit instruction 0xef000011 at offset 0x10 of the 64-byte header)
I've found various generations of documentation (which is why I don't stop looking when I find the first one by the way) with a key difference I'm interested in.
At offset 0x30 it was initially described as "four reserved words" but in later docs I find two changes to this field which may or may not conflict but I can't find anything that describes both unambiguously in one place.
When ARM went from 26-bit to 32-bit this field could be left at 00 or set to 1a (26) or 20 (32) to indicate whether the executable was 32-bit clean or 26-bit only.
But then there is documentation from the StrongArm era saying that if bit 31 of this field is set that the program is "StrongARM-ready".
Does this mean that the full complement of possibilities are all legitimate in this field? 0x00000000, 0x0000001a, 0x00000020, 0x10000000, 0x1000001a, and 0x10000020?
While it might seem that 26-bit and StrongARM would conflict the documents also state:

StrongARM does not support 26 bit configuration. It does support 26
bit   mode within a 32 bit configuration.

Does anyone know of a document or code sample which deals with the specifically?

You know that AIF headers are largely optional in older versions of RiscOS? And that a lot of binaries are still headerless?

@tofro I didn't see that explicitly in any of the docs I read actually but I did notice a few times that headerless was at least hinted at. I've never explored anything in the RiscOS universe until now.

IIRC it's not a single value word, but a flag word with different parts. Address width is encoded in the low byte, using 0, 26 and 32 as well as recently added 64 (x'40') for 64 bit binaries 64. The other bytes are to be used independent. I would think the actual RiscOS documentation containing some more details. Headerless was the original (Arthur) one. Also maybe helpful to note that AIF shares a format base with ASD, ALF and AOF.

Note that ARM adopted AIF and documents bit 8 as well at https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0041/c/ARM-Image-Format/The-layout-of-AIF/AIF-header - it looks to me like that variant of AIF may have been around in the RISC OS era, too, adding another set of allowed values.
